# How to disable graphql_flutter query backend every time build Query()

Tags: flutter, graphql

I got a `PageView` in the home page with `Query` for a list of data, and every time push to another route will causing `build`. And the `Query` in `build` will call backend Api and rerender. How to avoid the query?

- build method cannot be disabled and make the `Query` widget init in `initState` won't work
- I found the issue should be in here: https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/master/packages/graphql_flutter/lib/src/widgets/query.dart#L41 don't know why, any suggestions?

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Query(
    options: QueryOptions(
      document: queryDocument,
    ),
    builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
      print('will call backend each push and pop route and the build causing by state changes');
    }
  );
}
```

Expect the builder won't be alway call and to reduce the backend query. (I'm new to graphql_flutter and the document is not cover such case.)

Comment: why Query widget init in initState won't work?

Comment: @Praveena sorry, what i want to say is it can't avoid the query, it works as init in build method. I'm not sure, but I tried `StatefulWidget` will rebuild event it init in `initState `

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved in the next beta version https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter/versions/2.1.1-beta.2

See: https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/issues/412